# Troubleshooting javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, verisign

We have hosted our WebService in SSL and when we try to access that from our Java Client application we are getting the exception `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException`. To overcome this I have downloaded the SSL Certificate from WebService URL and imported it to Java TrustStore and then it worked fine. But this will be a complicated solution since our Java client application is running more than 1000s of computers. We obtained the certification from **VeriSign Class 3 International Server CA - G3**. Even the VeriSign is a Well known CA, why it is not listed in the java TrustStore by default? Can we fix this issue by doing some modifications in the server side or changing the certification?
Any Help will be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Java truststores are horribly out of date.  If the client only ever talks to one server, the best way is to bundle the server CA cert with the app and check against that.  It's either that or trawl through the last few releases of the java truststores, work out the common CA between them and get a cert from them.